# Laravel gives me a duplicate collection data

Tags: laravel, mongodb, collections

I want to sort my data by created date with this code :

```
        $comments = Instacomment::where('postid',$query->post['id'])->orderBy('comment.created_at', 'ASC')->paginate(10);
```

[image]

These are the results and Laravel gives me duplicate data! I don't know what to do !

Comment: Have you checked your DB? don't you have duplicate records on your DB?

Comment: Yes, I don't have duplicate records on my DB.

Comment: without orderBy it's working fine, but i want to sort my records

Comment: are you checked if your data are duplicated already inside your database? also share the full controller method for better understanding your code and give propper answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please try join table

```
        $comments = Instacomment::join('comments', 'instacomment.id', '=', 'comments.postid')->where('postid',$query->post['id'])->orderBy('comment.created_at', 'ASC')->paginate(10);
```

Comment: Magic !  Thank you!

Comment: Nice start @Monika